# How to programmatically draw on an OSM map with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have an application that needs to display a polygon on a map when the user opens the page. The user can then modify or delete the polygon manually.
Is there an example of how to draw a leaflet polygon using JavaScript?

Comment: Have you looked at the Leaflet.draw plug-in? http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to peeebeee I looked at the example [here](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/edithandlers.html) the code is simply

```
var poly = new L.Polygon( [
        [51.51, -0.1],
        [51.5, -0.06],
        [51.52, -0.03]
    ]);
map.addLayer(poly);
```